# What's the installation location convention for compiled libraries for a cross-compiler?

Tags: mingw, shared-libraries, cross-compiling, autotools, conventions

I'm using mingw32msvc to cross-compile from linux to win32.  This works well, and mingw uses Wine for this BTW.

Q: If I compile GLUT or FreeGLUT, where should I install the lib (as far as accepted convention)?  I googled it and the first answer was just give it an arbitrary name under /usr/local/**arbitrary**...

Better ideas?  I'll use /usr/local/**compilername** if there's no convention... in this case:

/usr/local/**i586-mingw32msvc**

It would be nice though if there's a convention so autoconf/automake/libtool look in the right places by default.

Answer (score 0):

There's no universal convention, as there is no universal place where compilers (or cross compilers) get installed.  That's why autotools exists.  Your name is fine as i586-mingw32msvc is pretty descriptive.